# Producing boxplot figures dynamically depending on number of columns in data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a python function to produce boxplots of data using python's matplotlib. I require this function to dynamically determine the number of figures and subplots based on the number of columns in the data. To make the figures readable I want the maximum number of subplots to be 4 by 4. If there are more than 16 I want to function to fill as many 4 by 4 figures as necessary then partially fill a final figure with the remainder.

For example, the data I currently have has 43 columns. I therefore want this function to produce 2 full figure containing 16 subplots each and one partially filled figure containing the remaining subplots. My problem is that I am stuck with the logic of writing such a function.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def boxplot_data(self,parameters_file):
    data = read_csv(parameters_file)
    header = data.keys()
    number_of_full_subplots = len(header)/16
    remainder = len(header)-(16*number_of_full_subplots)

    for i in range(0,number_of_full_subplots):
        plt.figure(i)
        for j in range(0,16):
            plt.subplot(4,4,j)
            boxplot(data[header[0:16]])
```

My plan was to iterate over the 'full subplots' first then iterate over the remainder however this method produces two identical figures.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Well python being 0 indexed ...

Comment: But the exact number is irrelevant since I would like the function to handle any number as a remainder

Comment: nitpick: `range(0,16)` can be replaced with `range(16)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the figures are identical because this line

```
            boxplot(data[header[0:16]])
```

does not change when `i` and `j` are incremented.

Replace it with

```
            boxplot(data[header[16*i+j]])
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def boxplot_data(self, parameters_file):
    data = read_csv(parameters_file)
    header = data.keys()
    number_of_full_subplots = len(header)/16

    for i in range(number_of_full_subplots):
        plt.figure(i)
        for j in range(16):
            plt.subplot(4, 4, j)
            boxplot(data[header[16*i+j]])
```

Comment: Excellent. This works perfectly except I needed to add '+1' to the 'i' loop to get the third figure. Thank you